# Simplificar y generar código captcha PHP

Tags: php, array, captcha

> Parece ser extenso pero es necesario para llegar a la idea.

Estoy desarrollando una imagen captcha una de mis ideas era ejemplar una imagen captcha similar al captcha de texto de google.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No he logrado crear el mismo estilo pero he generado una imagen captcha algo similar y creo que más original para un sistema propio.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El texto de la imagen la genero de esta forma:

```
imagettftext($image,25,mt_rand(-40,30),10,30,$black,"resources/fonts/font.ttf",$first); //tamaño de la fuente se realiza en la primera numeración(25)
imagettftext($image,25,mt_rand(-40,30),30,30,$black,"resources/fonts/font1.ttf",$second); //giro de la fuente se realiza en la segunda y tercera numeración (-40,30)
imagettftext($image,25,mt_rand(-40,30),50,30,$black,"resources/fonts/font2.ttf",$third); // Espacio la cuarta, alto la quinta (50,30)
imagettftext($image,25,mt_rand(-40,30),70,30,$black,"resources/fonts/font3.ttf",$fourth); // se puede cambiar varios modelo de fuente
```

Para un código más ordenado y optimizado trate de implementar un **array** pero la imagen no cargo.

```
$fonts = array(
    'font'  => array('spacing' => -3, 'minSize' => 27, 'maxSize' => 30, 'font' => 'resources/fonts/font.ttf'),
    'font1'  => array('spacing' =>-1.5,'minSize' => 28, 'maxSize' => 31, 'font' => 'resources/fonts/font1.ttf'),
    'font2' => array('spacing' => -2, 'minSize' => 24, 'maxSize' => 30, 'font' => 'resources/fonts/font2.ttf'),
    'font3'  => array('spacing' => -2, 'minSize' => 30, 'maxSize' => 38, 'font' => 'resources/fonts/font3.ttf'),
    'font4' => array('spacing' => -2, 'minSize' => 24, 'maxSize' => 34, 'font' => 'resources/fonts/font4.ttf'),
    'font5'     => array('spacing' => -2, 'minSize' => 28, 'maxSize' => 32, 'font' => 'resources/fonts/font5.ttf'),
    'font6' => array('spacing' =>-1.5,'minSize' => 28, 'maxSize' => 32, 'font' => 'resources/fonts/font6.ttf'),
    'font7'    => array('spacing' => -2, 'minSize' => 28, 'maxSize' => 34, 'font' => 'resources/fonts/font7.ttf'),
    'font8' => array('spacing' => -1, 'minSize' => 20, 'maxSize' => 28, 'font' => 'resources/fonts/font8.ttf'),
  );
```

El color de la fuente, un color diferente por cada actualización de la página:

```
$black = imagecolorallocate($image,rand(78,181),rand(163,35),rand(36,7));
```

El problema de este parámetro es conseguir el color a mi gusto con un **array** sería mucho mejor pero se me presentó el mismo problema anterior.

```
$black = array(
  array(17,70,121),
  array(12,133,25),
  array(114,26,7),
  array(38,44,10),
  array(16,113,52),
  array(123,29,26)
);
```

El color de fondo de la imagen es blanco

```
$white = imagecolorallocate($image,255,255,255);
```

No se si es posible crear un color de fondo transparente al añadir la variación de un `rgba`.

`rgba(82, 56, 76, 0.15);`

De esta forma:

`imagecolorallocate($image,82, 56, 76, 0.15);`

no imprime la imagen.

Analizado los diferentes tipos de captcha en la web he observado en algunos captcha donde el texto de la imagen es personalizado, esto se debe a librerías `.txt` personalizadas donde el archivo `.txt` tiene diferentes texto personalizados utilizados como texto de la imagen captcha.

A diferencia de una imagen aleatoria:

```
$source = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
```

Sería útil poder reemplazar un texto aleatorio a un texto personalizado mediante librerías `.txt`

Mi código captcha en el diseño actual **captcha.php**.

```
<?php
session_start();
$image = imagecreatetruecolor(120,50); //Ancho y alto de la imagen
$white = imagecolorallocate($image,255,255,255); // Color de fondo de la imagen
$black = imagecolorallocate($image,rand(78,181),rand(163,35),rand(36,7)); //Cambio de color de la fuente al refrescar

imagefill($image,0,0,$white);


imagerectangle($image,1,1,99,39 ,$white); // Configura el color del marco

$source = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
$first = $source[mt_rand(0,61)];
$second = $source[mt_rand(0,61)];
$third = $source[mt_rand(0,61)];
$fourth = $source[mt_rand(0,61)];
$_SESSION['captcha_secure'] = $first.$second.$third.$fourth;
imagettftext($image,25,mt_rand(-40,30),10,30,$black,"resources/fonts/Quixley.ttf",$first); //tamaño de la fuente se realiza en la primera numeracion -> (25)
imagettftext($image,25,mt_rand(-40,30),30,30,$black,"resources/fonts/AntykwaBold.ttf",$second); //giro de la fuente se realiza en la segunda y tercera numeración -> (-40,30)
imagettftext($image,25,mt_rand(-40,30),50,30,$black,"resources/fonts/Ding-DongDaddyO.ttf",$third); // Espacio la cuarta, alto la quinta -> (50,30)
imagettftext($image,25,mt_rand(-40,30),70,30,$black,"resources/fonts/Duality.ttf",$fourth); // se puede cambiar varios modelo de fuente

// Para añadir más caracters a la imagen se debe multiplicar estos parametros al caracters deseado
/*
imagettftext($image,25,mt_rand(-40,30),70,30,$black,"resources/fonts/Duality.ttf",$fourth);
*/

header("content-type:image/png");
imagepng($image);
?>
```

Comment: @rnd no amigo, no me molesta si no me he expresado bien pido disculpas.

Comment: Hola @MarcosGallardo la verdad no entiendo aún sobre utilizar `clase` el resultado que deseó tener es similar al texto del captcha de Google pero más de aquello es poder integrar el `array` al sistema **captcha** utilizar el `array` del color y el `array` de la fuente del captcha como nota **opcional** poder utilizar un texto personalizado en la imagen captcha a través de un archivo .txt pero es opcional el problema que se me ha presentado es poder vincular el `arry` para sustituir el código actual.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

En base a este [comentario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/40426/simplificar-y-generar-c%c3%b3digo-captcha-php#comment72043_40426)

> el resultado que deseó tener es similar al texto del captcha de Google pero más de aquello es poder integrar el array al sistema captcha utilizar el array del color y el array de la fuente del captcha como nota opcional poder utilizar un texto personalizado en la imagen captcha a través de un archivo `.txt`

- Para crear una imagen utilizando un `array` para los colores, otro `array` para las fuentes y obtener una palabra de un archivo `.txt`, puedes hacer lo siguiente:

  Archivo **captcha.php**

  ```
  <?php
  session_start();

  $source = file('palabras.txt'); // Archivo con palabras
  $word = trim($source[rand(0, count($source) - 1)]); // Obtenemos una palabra
  $charsLength = strlen($word); // Cantidad de letras de la palabra
  $marginLeftRight = 10; // Margen izq derecho
  $marginTopBottom = 10; // Margen sup inf
  $fonts = array( // Arreglo de fuentes
      array('spacing' =>   -3, 'minSize' => 27, 'maxSize' => 30, 'font' => 'fonts/Quixley.ttf'),
      array('spacing' => -1.5, 'minSize' => 28, 'maxSize' => 31, 'font' => 'fonts/AntykwaBold.ttf'),
      array('spacing' =>   -2, 'minSize' => 24, 'maxSize' => 30, 'font' => 'fonts/Ding-DongDaddyO.ttf'),
      array('spacing' =>   -2, 'minSize' => 28, 'maxSize' => 30, 'font' => 'fonts/Duality.ttf')
  );

  $rgbs = array( // Arreglo de colores
    array(17,70,121),
    array(12,133,25),
    array(114,26,7),
    array(38,44,10),
    array(16,113,52),
    array(123,29,26)
  );

  // Generamos la palabra
  $_SESSION['captcha_secure'] = '';
  $chars = array();
  $imageWidth = 0;
  $imageHeight = 0;
  for ($i = 0; $i < $charsLength; $i++) {

      //
      $font = $fonts[mt_rand(0, count($fonts) - 1)];
      $char = array(
          'char'     => $word[$i],
          'font'     => $font['font'],
          'spacing'  => $font['spacing'],
          'size'     => rand($font['minSize'], $font['maxSize']),
          'angle'    => rand(-20, 20)
      );
      $coords = imagettfbbox ($char['size'], $char['angle'], $char['font'] , $char['char']);
      $imageWidth += ($coords[2] - $char['spacing']); // Sumamos el ancho del char actual
      $imageHeight = max($imageHeight, $char['size']);

      $_SESSION['captcha_secure'] .= $char['char']; // Concatenamos el char
      $chars[] = $char; // Guardamos la config del char
  }
  $imageWidth += $marginLeftRight * 2; // Sumamos el margen configurado
  $imageHeight += $marginTopBottom * 2; // Sumamos el margen configurado

  // Creamos la imagen
  $image = imagecreatetruecolor($imageWidth, $imageHeight); //Ancho y alto de la imagen

  // Fondo
  $white = imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 255, 255); // Color de fondo de la imagen
  imagecolortransparent($image, $white); // Transpartente
  imagefill($image, 0, 0, $white);

  // Color palabra
  list($r, $g, $b) = $rgbs[mt_rand(0, count($rgbs) - 1)];
  $wordColor = imagecolorallocate($image, $r, $g, $b);

  // Palabra
  $x = $marginLeftRight;
  $y = ($imageHeight / 2) + $marginTopBottom;
  foreach ($chars as $char) {

      // Color del char
      $coords = imagettftext($image, $char['size'], $char['angle'], $x, $y, $wordColor, $char['font'], $char['char']);

      $x += $coords[2] - $x - $char['spacing'];
  }

  header("content-type:image/png");
  imagepng($image);
  ```

  Archivo **palabras.txt** (*sin renglones en blanco*)

  ```
   globo
   chapuza
   varar
   poisa
   follar
   gozar
   cochina
   barbado
  ```

  Archivo **index.php**

  ```
  <div style="background: #ccc; display: inline-block;">
     <img src="captcha.php" />
  </div>
  ```

  Resultados:

  [image][image][image]
- Para hacer una imagen similar a la de *Google*

  Te recomiendo que leas indagues sobre la librería [`Imagen Magick`](http://php.net/manual/es/book.imagick.php). [Este articulo](http://php.net/manual/es/book.imagick.php) te puede dar un par de ideas.

  Aquí un `snippet` a modo de ejemplo:

  ```
  <?php

  /* Creamos un objeto Imagick */
  $image = new Imagick();

  /* Creamos un objeto ImagickPixel para el fondo */
  $bg = new ImagickPixel();
  $bg->setColor('white'); // Blanco

  /* Creamos un ImagickDraw para configurar la fuente, tamaño, color y posición */
  $draw = new ImagickDraw();
  $draw->setFont('fonts/Duality.ttf');
  $draw->setFontSize( 50 );
  $draw->setFillColor("navy");
  $draw->setGravity(Imagick::GRAVITY_CENTER);
  $fontWidth = 

  /* Texto */
  $string = 'gozar';

  /* Creamos la imagen */
  $image->newImage(120, 60, $bg); 

  /* Escribimos el texto en la imagen */
  $image->annotateImage($draw, 0, 0, 0, $string);

  /* Arremolinamos la imagen (swirl) */
  $image->swirlImage(45);

  /* Agregamos el dibujo. */
  $image->drawImage($draw);

  /* Seteamos el formato */
  $image->setImageFormat('png');


  header( "Content-Type: image/{$image->getImageFormat()}" );
  echo $image->getImageBlob();
  ```

  Resultado:

  [image]

Comment: Hola @MarcosGallardo gracias por la respuesta, probe el ejemplo amigo funciona, pero sin embargo existe un pequeño error refresque la pagina para ver los tipo de impresión de la imagen en unas cuantas veces que refresque la página tomando en cuenta el número de veces que refresque la página 3 -> 4 -> 12 en una de ellas la imagen no imprime queda solo un marco blanco con el borde pero no imprime la imagen del texto del captcha al refrescar el número de veces ya mencionado. Pensé que el error era alguna fuente que no estaba en la carpeta `fonts` pero todas las fuentes están en la carpeta.

Comment: Amigo sobre el color de la fuente, como obtengo un solo color de la fuente en vez de un color diferente por cada letra.

Comment: Hola @MarcosGallardo con la nueva actualización de obtener una palabra desde un archivo `.txt` ya no muestra el error de la impresión de la imagen del antiguo código Un **pequeño detalle** es a la hora de actualizar la página la imagen del texto suele imprimirse seguidamente el mismo texto al actualizar. Sobre crear el texto similar a Google en texto curvados y Ondulación del texto verticales e horizontales encontré [este código](http://ideone.com/ustrYF) la documentación del codigo es algo similar al tema que estamos tratando en mi pregunta [http://ideone.com/ustrYF](http://ideone.com/ustrYF)

Comment: Puedes echarle un último vistazo a la documentación antes de seleccionar la pregunta, quizás la documentación pueda servir de algo para interactuar en el tema más a fondo :) Saludos.

Comment: @J.Doe, he actualizado mi pregunta. He añadido el calculo alto automático y corregido espacio entre letras. Con respecto a la probabilidad de que aparezca la misma palabra, se puede corregir si metes 1000 (mil) o mas palabras en el `.txt`. Respecto al `snippet` puedes publicar tu propia respuesta utilizando ese código.

Comment: Gracias por el tiempo dedicado a mi pregunta, solo por curiosidad existe algún plugin para reproducir el texto de la imagen a audio.

Comment: @J.Doe te aconsejo que crees una nueva pregunta para que recibas una mejor respuesta. Mientras tanto puede que [esta respuesta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/40530/como-descargar-audio-generado-con-responsivevoice-en-un-archivo-mp3-con-javascr/40542#40542). te sirva de algo.

Comment: El color transparente del fondo causaba un defecto en los caracteres medio borrosas con bordes blanco lo solucione de esta manera `$white = imagecolorallocatealpha($image, 120, 120, 120, 0.4);` y comente esta línea de código `//imagecolortransparent($image, $white);` le aplique un color gris al fondo del captcha a una página con background gris es como si el fondo del captcha fuera transparente al tener el mismo fondo, me puedes ayudar a crear un marco o margen blanco a la imagen captcha trate de esta manera: `imagerectangle($image,1,1,99,39 ,$white);` pero no funciona.

Comment: @J.Doe, seguramente no te anduvo ya que has usado el mismo color que creaste para el fondo. Intenta crear un nuevo color, por ejemplo: `$white = imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 255, 255);
imagerectangle($image,1,1,99,39 ,$white);`. PD: Para el tamaño del rectángulo deberías usar las variables `$imageWidth y $imageHeight` y recuerda restarles el ancho del mismo.

Comment: que tal amigo, añadí mil palabras y un poco más y sigue saliendo ese error de mostrar la misma palabra al actualizar el captcha?

Comment: @J.Doe, Si consideras que la probabilidad de que una palabra se repita es muy alta, podrías crear una nueva pregunta para recibir distintas soluciones para este problema especifico.

Comment: Si es considerable *(que una palabra se repita)* pero no tiene sentido que por ejemplo salga esta palabra: **Holaa** y al actualizar una nueva palabra te repita la misma palabra: **Holaa** No tiene lógica?

Comment: @J.Doe, para obtener la palabra el código utiliza [`rand`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.rand.php), la cual, devuelve un número aleatorio... no hay ninguna "lógica" extra. Como ya te comente antes, si consideras que necesitas mejorar dicha parte, te aconsejo que **crees una nueva pregunta**, ya que [tu pregunta actual](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/40426/simplificar-y-generar-c%C3%B3digo-captcha-php/41875) solo se limita a lo que esta resaltado en amarillo en [mi respuesta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/a/41875/16597).

Answer (score 2):

J. Doe, has intentado usar `imagefill()` y rellenarlo con el color asignado `imagecolorallocatealpha()` que puede tener un valor entre 0 y `127`, es decir, 0 indica completamente opaco mientras que 127 indica completamente transparente.

> **Nota:** imagecolorallocatealpha() se comporta de forma idéntica a imagecolorallocate() con la adición del parámetro de transparencia alpha.

Podría quedar algo así:

```
$white = imagecolorallocatealpha($image,255,255,255,80); //Fondo imagen.
imagefill($image,0,0,$white);//Rellenar.
```

Código fuente SO:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8437665/how-to-create-an-image-with-transparent-background

Manual `imagecolorallocatealpha()`:

- http://php.net/manual/es/function.imagecolorallocatealpha.php

Manual `imagefill()`:

- http://php.net/manual/es/function.imagefill.php

Answer (score 0):

si usas imagecolortransparent()?

aca te dejo un ejemplo:

```
<?php
// Crear una imagen de 55x30
$im = imagecreatetruecolor(55, 30);
$rojo = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 0, 0);
$negro = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);

// Hacer el fondo transparente
imagecolortransparent($im, $negro);

// Dibujar un rectángulo rojo
imagefilledrectangle($im, 4, 4, 50, 25, $rojo);

// Guardar la imagen
imagepng($im, './imagecolortransparent.png');
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```