# ¿Como descargar audio generado con ResponsiveVoice en un archivo MP3 con Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Estoy usando [`responsivevoice.js`](https://responsivevoice.org/api/) para generar audio desde texto y quiero guardar el audio en un `mp3`.

```
<script src="http://code.responsivevoice.org/responsivevoice.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  responsiveVoice.setDefaultVoice("Spanish Female");
  responsiveVoice.speak("Hola");
</script>
```

Comment: Con [esta URL de ejemplo](http://responsivevoice.org/responsivevoice/getvoice.php?t=Hola&tl=es-ES) te permite descargar el mp3 que genera. O quieres descargarla autoamaticamente?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Existe una `API` (`responsivevoice.org/responsivevoice/getvoice.php`) que ofrece `ResponsiveVoice` para generar audios dinamicamente.

**Descargar usando *JS* y *HTML5***

Utilizando dicha `API` y el atributo [`download`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#Attributes), podrías hacer lo siguiente:

> Atributo `download`: No es soportado por `IE`, solo a partir de `Edge`. Además `Firefox` sólo admite vínculos de descarga del mismo origen, por lo que, en lugar de descargarlo, sera redireccionado al sitio.

```js
var texto = document.getElementById('texto');
var play = document.getElementById('play');
var download = document.getElementById('download');

play.onclick = function() {
  responsiveVoice.speak(texto.value, 'Spanish Female');
}
texto.onblur = function () {
  var url = '//responsivevoice.org/responsivevoice/getvoice.php?t=' + 
      encodeURIComponent(texto.value) + '&tl=es-ES';

  download.href = url;
}
texto.onblur();
```

```html
<script src="http://code.responsivevoice.org/responsivevoice.js"></script>
Texto: <input id="texto" value="hola mundo" /><br/>
<button type="button" id="play">Play</button>
<a download id="download">Descargar</a>
```

**Descargar usando *API* propia**

Otra solución (*y para el caso soporta por todos los navegadores*) sería que implementaras tu propia `API` para descargar el audio.

Usando `PHP` podrías hacer lo siguiente:

*Archivo getaudio.php*

```
<?php
$texto = $_GET['texto'];
header ("Content-type: octet/stream");
header ("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=audio.mp3;");
// Usamos la API de ResponsiveVoice para generar el audio
echo file_get_contents('http://responsivevoice.org/responsivevoice/getvoice.php?t=' . urlencode($texto) . '&tl=es-ES');
exit;
?>
```

*Archivo HTML*

```
<script src="http://code.responsivevoice.org/responsivevoice.js"></script>
Texto: <input id="texto" value="hola mundo" /><br/>
<button type="button" id="play">Play</button>
<a target="_blank" id="download">Descargar</a>
<script>
var texto = document.getElementById('texto');
var play = document.getElementById('play');
var download = document.getElementById('download');

play.onclick = function() {
  responsiveVoice.speak(texto.value, 'Spanish Female');
}
texto.onblur = function () {
  // Usamos NUESTRA API para descargar el audio
  var url = '//dominio.com/path/getaudio.php?texto=' +
    encodeURIComponent(texto.value);
  download.href = url;
}
texto.onblur();
</script>
```