# Descargar un TTS

Tags: javascript, html5, apigoogle

quería preguntar como se podría agregar un botón para descargar el audio según el texto ingresado.
Si no existe la posibilidad de hacerlo, ¿Alguna recomendación?.
Adjunto el código de lo que llevo avanzado.

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.responsivevoice.org/responsivevoice.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('dia_final') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
    <label>Mensaje</label>
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" name="text">
      <a href="#" class="say">Escuchar Texto!</a>
    </div>
    <audio src="" hidden class=speech></audio>
    <script>
      $("a.say").on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var text = $("input[name=text]").val();
        responsiveVoice.speak(text, "Spanish Female");
        text = encodeURIComponent(text);
        var url = "http://"
      })
    </script>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Aqui hay una publicación relacionado con lo que solicitas [¿Como descargar audio generado con ResponsiveVoice en un archivo MP3 con Javascript?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/40530/como-descargar-audio-generado-con-responsivevoice-en-un-archivo-mp3-con-javascr/40542)

Comment: Muchas gracias la revisare

Comment: @mhplur no me funciono :( la descarga no se me efectúa, conoces alguna otra posibilidad ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Que tal hice la prueba con el código que se encuentra en el Post del comentario [¿Como descargar audio generado con ResponsiveVoice en un archivo MP3 con Javascript?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/40542/4413)

```js
var texto = document.getElementById('texto');
var play = document.getElementById('play');
var download = document.getElementById('download');

play.onclick = function(event) {
  responsiveVoice.speak(texto.value, 'Spanish Female');
}
texto.onblur = function () {
  var url = '//responsivevoice.org/responsivevoice/getvoice.php?t=' + 
      encodeURIComponent(texto.value) + '&tl=es-ES';

  download.href = url;
}
texto.onblur();
```

```html
<script src="http://code.responsivevoice.org/responsivevoice.js"></script>
Texto: <input id="texto" value="hola mundo" /><br/>
<button type="button" id="play">Play</button>
<a download id="download">Descargar</a>
```

Lo Probé desde el `IDE` de `Eclipse` en `Google Chrome` y funciona correctamente, permite reproducir y al presionar en Descargar me muestra lo siguiente y me permite descargar el archivo en formato `mp3`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se descarga un archivo con el nombre `getvoice.mp3`, trata de probarlo de esta forma.

(Nota: parece que suceden algunos inconvenientes con otros navegadores como lo explica en la publicación). Lo probé en `FireFox` y no se puede descargar, solo reproducir:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]