# Como hacer para descargar un File automáticamente

Tags: javascript, java, jquery

mi pregunta és si hay alguna posibilidad de, teniendo un file

```
File file = new File (prueba.csv);
```

con su contenido

```
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(file);
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append("AAAAA");
```

mediante un click en este botón

```
<button type="button" class="descargarCSV">Descargar Excel</button>
```

Hay alguna función en JavaScript o JQuery, que pueda hacer que se descargue automáticamente este file?
Que al hacer click al botón directamente salga descargado como en la imagen. Gracias!

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo esta función de otro sitio pero creo que no hace exactamente lo que quiero

```
    function downloadCSV(args) {
          var data, filename, link;
          var csv = "";
          for(var i = 0; i < args.chart.options.data.length; i++){
            csv += convertChartDataToCSV({
              data: args.chart.options.data[i].dataPoints
            });
          }
          if (csv == null) return;

          filename = args.filename || 'chart-data.csv';

          if (!csv.match(/^data:text\/csv/i)) {
            csv = 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + csv;
          }
          
          data = encodeURI(csv);
          link = document.createElement('a');
          link.setAttribute('href', data);
          link.setAttribute('download', filename);
          document.body.appendChild(link); // Required for FF
            link.click(); 
            document.body.removeChild(link);   
        }
```

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Como descargar audio generado con ResponsiveVoice en un archivo MP3 con Javascript?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/40530/como-descargar-audio-generado-con-responsivevoice-en-un-archivo-mp3-con-javascr)

Comment: Que yo sepa no, no uso ResponseVoice, entiendo que quiero hacer lo mismo pero descargando un archivo normal.

Comment: Por lo que indicas al principio, que parece un fragmento de código Java, faltaría saber qué es lo que te devuelve el back o endpoint que te va a devolver ese fichero. Es decir, ¿lo devuelve como un base64? ¿como un texto plano? Si pudieras aportar algo más de esa información para poder orientarte en la solución es de agradecer.